# Where is the file I saved on my USB flash drive?

Tags: mount, libreoffice, usb-drive, data-recovery, data-loss

I am running Ubuntu from a pendrive and I saved a document in LibreOffice. My computer shut down and now I can't find it anywhere!

I've read that if running Ubuntu from pendrive it saves documents onto the USB flash drive, but they can't be seen while actually running Ubuntu from USB. So how can I find my saved  document?

Also, is there a way to virtual mount the Ubuntu ISO from the USB to the computer? I tried to install, but I don't have enough memory on my hard disk - only 3GB.

I'm just a new user, so please help me in the most basic, step-by-step way if you can. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: First of all, please explain how you created the Ubuntu USB pendrive (tool, version, how-to you found, etc.) and the **options** you selected. You can create a Live USB image *with* the option to save changes you make to the Live environment, but that's not on by default! Secondly, explain where you saved the document (location on flash drive). Include all information *in* your question by **editing** it.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a Ubuntu pendrive changes will not be saved across reboots unless you have enabled [persistence](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/what-is-persistent-linux/). My guess is that you did not set any persistence for your pendrive any therefore any changes you make or files you saved will not be saved. There are a couple ways to check but the easiest is to boot to the USB, make some changes(change your background and make a couple files), then reboot and see if the changes are there.

I bet you will find they are not. So remake you pendrive, but this time with persistence.
A simple way to do this is using UNetBootin.

1. Download UNetBootin
2. Select Ubuntu as the distribution and I would go with either 12.04 or 13.04 as the version
3. Set the persistence to 4000MB. 
   *note:* The max is 4GB, there are ways to overcome if you want to do some research.
4. Make sure your USB drive is selected and hit OK

Now you can save changes and files across reboots.